# NSURLSession : getting null resumedata when downloading is running and in between that internet connection will change as ON to OFF mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using NSURLSession for downloading zip file from server.
following task working perfectly

- Pause and resume downloading
- Get Progress of downloading
- Get Notification of when internet is active or not active

**but there is major problem**

While downloading is going on at that time if internet connection is gone that time I get notification about it but there I can stored NSData which I will again assign when internet connection will come.
In internet connective method I get null data from

```
[downloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData:^(NsData * resumeData){
NSLog(@"Resume data %@",resumeData);  // GETTING **"NULL"**

}
```

Please help!

Comment: I am stuck here please any one have any idea about this problem please give some comments or ans on that. My app is just paused only for that bug :(

Comment: I know its quite old but I am struggling with the same issue right now. Have you found the solution for the same? Thanks.

Comment: No still not found any solution for this so I move on AFNetworking framework

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue ? because I am getting same. :(